# Creating a mask using C++ bit shift intrinsics

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, bit, bit-shift, intrinsics

Let's say we want to create a mask of type `unsigned short` with contiguous set of `len` 1s starting from position `a` with as little instructions as possible. The most popular way to do this is

```cpp
T mask = ((1 << len)-1) << a;
```

Where `T` is any built-in unsigned integral type.

My question is the following: If `a != 0 && a + len < DIGITS`, where `DIGITS` is a compile time constant equal to the number of bits in a word of type`T`, is there anything we can do (compiler builtins or intrinsics) to save even a single instruction? I am looking for answers as generic as possible (architecture and compiler neutral), however answers that only work on specific systems or in specific contexts are also of use, primarily when they are compile-time deducible contexts.

**Edit/Leaderboard:**

-**4 instructions**: [`_bzhi_u32(-1,len) << first_pos`](https://godbolt.org/z/ppuHVP)
(however as people discussed in the comments, I don't know much about the latency of the _bhzi instruction)

-**6 instructions** (by just adding the `-O1` flag)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194199/discussion-on-question-by-bryce-kille-creating-a-mask-using-c-bit-shift-intrin).